# Android Custom Adapter - ArrayAdapter requires resource ID to be a Textview error

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I created a custom adapter in order to have a title, description and image for my list items, however it keeps throwing this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

I understand why it would throw that if I was using the standard Android adapter, but I thought by making your own adapter you can pretty much avoid this. Is there something I'm missing?

Here is my adapter class:

```
package homepage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter_Homepage extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> titles;
    private final ArrayList<String> descriptions;

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, description;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public Adapter_Homepage(Context context, ArrayList<String> titles, ArrayList<String> descriptions) {
        this.context = context;
        this.titles = titles;
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
    }


    public String getItemTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }

    public String getItemDescription(int position) {
        return descriptions.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_activity_item, null);
            // configure view holder
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            holder.description = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            holder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(getItemTitle(position));
        holder.description.setText(getItemDescription(position));
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Here is my activity class:

```
public class Activity_Homepage extends Activity {

private ListView listview;
private Adapter_Homepage adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_activity_listview);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    titles.add("Aaron Rodgers");
    titles.add("Jordy Nelson");

    ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    descriptions.add("Quarterback");
    descriptions.add("Wide Receiver");

    adapter = new Adapter_Homepage(this, titles, descriptions);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(global_OnItemClickListener);


}

final AdapterView.OnItemClickListener global_OnItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using an `ArrayAdapter` instead of your custom implementation and you are not providing the `id` of a `TextView`.

Also, you need to make sure that you are returning the correct values on your `BaseAdapter` methods. Returning `0` on `getCount()` and `null` on `getItem()` will make your app crash.

Comment: I edited in my main activity class. It looks to be using my custom adapter so providing the textview id should not matter.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Changing the return values seemed to fix the exception, however the only the description textview shows up now.